# When to receive TCP message

Tags: c#, tcp

I am creating an application that communicates with a server, using asyncronous TCP sockets.

Now, I made a function called `'Receive'` to receive incoming packets of different clients on the server using `beginreceive` , the thing is, that I'm not sure when to call the function...

So how would I check if there is a packet waiting to be received or something like that, some kind of `OnReceive` hook? or is there not other way to already call `BeginReceive` at the moment the client successfully connects to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a thread for every client that connects. In that client you call the `BeginReceive` method and call it again everytime you received something.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm asking when to do that, would you already call BeginReceive on the start of a successfull connection or would you call it when there's actually something to receive?

Comment: If the client is the first to start the communication then you would call the `BeginReceive` right after you accepted the clients connection.